# Xamarin iOS constraints problems

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, autolayout, constraints

So I'm pretty new to designing iOS apps but have experience creating GUIs in Java and .NET (not that either of those apply to mobile app design).

Anyway, my question is this: how do I properly use constraints/auto layout/size classes to create a dynamic home screen that adapts appropriately (shrinking or growing) depending on screen size? The home screen is basically a springboard consisting of six image buttons. When I use the "recommended constraints" that Xamarin Studio recommends this is what shows up in an iPhone 5s simulator:
[iOS generic layout on an iPhone 5s simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpytj.jpg)

Can anyone please give me some pointers regarding working with constraints, and explain how to make it so that my image buttons become smaller and closer together on a smaller screen size (and larger and further spaced apart on a larger screen)? I would love to hear from someone who is experienced in iOS 8/9 auto layout design...Xamarin Studio experience would just be a plus!

EDIT: here's a link to my project repo on github. If you go into CPTCAppNew/CPTCAppNew.iOS you can see Main.storyboard. Sorry that I wasn't able to post the storyboard XML code directly to stackoverflow :/

https://github.com/drewbritton/MyCPTC.git

Comment: Are you able to post your storyboard or nib file? Generally the "recommended constraints" just at Top,Leading,Width and Height which is probably not what you are looking for. If you post your storyboard or nib I'll take a look and see what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your reply! I posted a link in the original post :]

Comment: May not be what you want to hear, but in the end I got so frustrated with the GUI approach to layout and constraints that I went with a fully programmatic approach. With that I then used Cirrious.Fluentlayout and never looked back!